# Firefox, Chrome canvas conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

I've made this [pen](http://codepen.io/vahidseo/pen/kFzqI), which consists of two canvas elements. One is a beating heart, and the other one is a heart monitor, if you will.

The heart monitor colors do not seem right in Google Chrome browser, and in Mozilla Firefox, there's a weird dark pulse trail. Do you know what the problem is? How do I fix it?

Comment: can you define what "the color do not seem right" means exactly?

Comment: @vahidseo - Do you mean the grid that is within the container of the heart monitor has brighter colors in Chrome?

Comment: Well, if you check the rgba values I've specified, you'll notice that the grid should look a little green, not grey. And also the background should be darker. Firefox renders the colors just fine. But it also renders a dark pulse trail which shouldn't be there. That part, Chrome renders fine.

Comment: looks exactly the same for me in both FF29 and Chrome35.

Comment: Mine: Chrome 35.0.1916.114 m and Firefox 29.0.1, and they look pretty different. Does anyone else have this problem, or it's just me?